# Remove space before itemize

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize

I have defined a `\newcommand` called `\NewEntry` that takes two parameters and prints one above the other.

```
\newcommand{\NewEntry}[2]{
    #1 \\
    #2
}
```

Calling this command by

```
\NewEntry{ENTRY}
{\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
\item First Item
\item Second Item
\end{itemize}
}
```

leads to a vertical space between "ENTRY" and "First item", even though `topsep` is set to zero.

[image]

I would like to remove this space.

If the command is called by

```
\NewEntry{ENTRY}
{Blah\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
\item First Item
\item Second Item
\end{itemize}
}
```

then "Blah" occupies the space that I am trying to remove.

[image]

A MWE follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[2]{
    #1 \\
    #2
}

\begin{document}
    \NewEntry{ENTRY}
    {Blah\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
    \item First Item
    \item Second Item
    \end{itemize}
    }
    \NewEntry{ENTRY}
    {\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
    \item First Item
    \item Second Item
    \end{itemize}
    }
\end{document}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this `\NewEntry` macro does not seem very well structured but I can see that you are trying to structure your text. If you let us know what it is supposed to represent/typeset maybe we can suggest a better way to package it...

Comment: For example, if the second argument is always a list of two items you could instead require three arguments for `\NewEntry` and format the itemize inside it...(just as an example of what I'm talking about)

Comment: @Bordaigorl Thank you for the suggestions. I have asked a new [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270455/removing-space-resulting-from-newcommand-definition), providing more details on the context of the problem, since it looks like the structure of my document needs imrpovement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[2]{%
    #1 \par\noindent
    #2}

\begin{document}
    \NewEntry{ENTRY}{}
    Blah
    \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
    \item First Item
    \item Second Item
    \end{itemize}

    \NewEntry{ENTRY}{}        
    \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
    \item First Item
    \item Second Item
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

`itemize` starts in a new line by itself, so adding one more `\\` in your macro will lead to a blank line. Replacing this with `\par\noindent` can solve the problem. Further, you may remember adding an empty pair `{}` so perhaps you might add another argument later.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the faulty `\\` after `#1` -- it does no good there. Leave an empty blank line to separate the items. In my point of view this however no really convincing way to use `itemize` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[2]{%
    #1% 

    #2%
}

\begin{document}
    \NewEntry{ENTRY}
    {\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
    \item First Item
    \item Second Item
    \end{itemize}
    }
    \NewEntry{ENTRY}{%
      \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
    \item First Item
    \item Second Item
    \end{itemize}
    }
\end{document}
```

**Some suggestions to improve this**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newlist{notopsepitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[notopsepitemize,1]{label={\textbullet},topsep=0pt}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_tonychief_item_clist
\NewDocumentCommand{\NewEntry}{O{}mm}{
\clist_set:Nn \l_tonychief_item_clist {#3}
    #2

    \begin{notopsepitemize}[#1]
    \item 
      \clist_use:Nn \l_tonychief_item_clist {\item} %
    \end{notopsepitemize}
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \NewEntry{ENTRY}{Item One, Item Two, Item Three, Item Four}%

    \NewEntry[topsep=20pt]{Other ENTRY}{Item One, Item Two, Item Three, Item Four}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If it is to be used with `itemize` like this, here is an `enumitem` way using `before=Entry`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,before=Entry]
    \item First Item
    \item Second Item
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great to learn about `before`!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Christian that a `\par` is better than `\\` and that in general it seems a rather odd way of constructing your `\NewEntry` command.

However just for reference, you may use a negative space in the argument with the itemize:

```
\NewEntry{ENTRY}
{\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
\item First Item
\item Second Item
\end{itemize}
}
```

Still, I would **not** recommend such a construction.

Try instead to see if you could make your command more "semantic".