# Removing space resulting from newcommand definition

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize

My document is a list of entries. Here is an example with three entries:
[image]

All entries have a title and two subtitles. These are followed by text, bullet points or a combination of the two. Note that I would like a big gap between different entries and a smaller one between the subtitles and the rest of each entry.

I have defined a `\newcommand` called `\NewEntry` to specify the information that goes into each entry:

```
\newcommand{\NewEntry}[4]{
{\setlength{\parskip}{20pt}
    #1 \\
    #2 - #3 \\[3pt]}
    #4 \par
}
```

Calling this command with the code presented at the end, leads to the following output:

[image]

This is satisfactory, apart from the space between the subtitles and the first bullet item in the third entry, which is too big. I asked how to solve this in a previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270385/remove-space-before-itemize), without providing the general context. From the answers, it was clear that the extra space is a result of combining `\itemize` (which starts at a new line by default) with the `\\` in my `\NewEntry` code. Also, some answers explicitely said or implied that there may be a better way to structure my document and suggested that I provide the context, which is what I have tried to do here.

I am looking forward to suggestions about the best way to deal with this problem (including structural changes).

A MWE follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[4]{
{\setlength{\parskip}{20pt}
    #1 \\
    #2 - #3 \\[3pt]}
    #4 \par
}

\begin{document}

\NewEntry{TITLE}{SUBTITLE 1}{SUBTITLE 2}
{\lipsum[13]}

\NewEntry{TITLE}{SUBTITLE 1}{SUBTITLE 2}
{Some Text
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item First Item
\item Second Item
\end{itemize}
}

\NewEntry{TITLE}{SUBTITLE 1}{SUBTITLE 2}
{\begin{itemize}[nosep]
 \item First Item
 \item Second Item
 \end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: End of line is a space. Comment it out if you don't want the space. But ending a line with `\\ ` is almost always wrong outside e.g. `tabular` and `array` environments. Why aren't you using `\section`, `\subsection` etc.? What's wrong with the space between the subtitles exactly?

Comment: (Expanding on cfr's first sentence.) Spaces are often significant in macro definitions. Your definition of `\NewEntry` contains three 'explicit' instructions to TeX that you want it to add space: after `[4]{`, after `{20pt}`, and after `[3pt]}`. You might want to read [this question and its answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/8528).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: entries]

It is a bit hard to say how best to structure it without more context. Why, for example, are you not using `\section*{}` and `\subsection*{}` or similar?

Assuming you do not want to do that for some reason, the following code produces the output above using a `\NewEntryX{}{}{}{}` command and a new unordered list, `entries`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem,xparse}
\newlist{entries}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[entries]{label=\textbullet,nosep,topsep=.5em}
\NewDocumentCommand \NewEntryX { m m m m }{%
  {\setlength\parindent{0pt}%
  \vskip 20pt plus 1ex minus .5ex
  \par
  \MakeUppercase{#1}\par
  \MakeUppercase{#2 --- #3}\vskip .5em plus .1em minus .05em\par
  #4}\par}


\begin{document}

  \NewEntryX{Title}{Subtitle 1}{Subtitle 2}
  {\lipsum[13]}

  \NewEntryX{Title}{Subtitle 1}{Subtitle 2}
  {Some Text
    \begin{entries}
      \item First Item
      \item Second Item
    \end{entries}}

  \NewEntryX{Title}{Subtitle 1}{Subtitle 2}
  {\begin{entries}
      \item First Item
      \item Second Item
    \end{entries}}

\end{document}
```

Note that as much formatting as possible is done in the macro definition e.g. you enter the headings with normal titling capitalisation and the command uppercases them. This makes it a lot easier if you change your mind and want them to be bold, say, or small-caps later.

Comment: A group is necessary to confine the setting of `\parindent`